# useBootstrap no está funcionando para implementar Laravel 8.0

Tags: laravel, bootstrap, laravel-8

Tengo un problema para implementar Laravel 8.0, y es que uno de sus cambios que debo implementar es el mantener Bootstrap como editor CSS fijo
El problema es que me sale "Undefined method 'useBootstrap'cuando quiero implementarlo, este es el código:
Agradeceré que me puedan apoyar con alguna solución, gracias

```
    <?php

namespace App\Providers;

use Carbon\Carbon;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Blade;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Pagination\Paginator;
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

    class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
    {
        
        /**
         * Bootstrap any application services.
         *
         * @return void
         */
        public function boot()
        {
            Schema::defaultStringLength(191);
            Blade::withoutComponentTags();
            Paginator::useBootstrap(); // Agrega esta línea
        }
    
        /**
         * Register any application services.
         *
         * @return void
         */
        public function register()
        {
            //
        }
    }
```

Comment: ¿Estas seguro que es la version 8 de laravel y no una anterior? A partir de la v8, la función [public static function useBootstrap()](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/99fa2e33da0e6534bdc698bc6e6e685303111d5f/src/Illuminate/Pagination/AbstractPaginator.php#L610) está definida, pero [en versiones anteriores no existía](https://laravel.com/api/7.x/Illuminate/Pagination/Paginator.html). Si es así, lo único que se me ocurre es que no se están cargando bien las clases, para lo que puedes probar correr `composer dump-autoload` a ver si lo soluciona.